# Setting mouse scroll wheel to scroll less than 1 line in Windows

Tags: windows-7, mouse, scrolling, mouse-wheel, scroll-wheel

I am trying to fine tune my mouse scroll wheel behavior.
When I go to Control Panel > Mouse Properties, there is the setting for [Roll the wheel one notch to scroll]. The minimum allowed setting is 1 line.

How can I set this to be less than 1 line? Optimally I want it to be 1 pixel at time.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if [this](http://download.cnet.com/Move-Mouse-One-Pixel-at-a-Time-with-Key/3000-2317_4-75362599.html) will help , bcs i have never used it , but you can give it a try.

Also there is a "[How to Boost Your Mouse Pointing Accuracy in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/boost-your-mouse-pointing-accuracy-in-windows/)"

Hope it helps !!

Comment: It says that it is for keyboard stroke, my question is about mouse scroll wheel.